# Using PyTest fixture without passing them

Tags: python, pytest

I am using PyTest framework for writing and running my tests.
I have implemented a concrete logger:

```
class Logger(object):

    class LogFormats:
        ...

    def __init__(self, testname ,setup ,silent=True):
        """
        creating concrete logger for pytest.
        the logger will create a file for the test in specific test directory in quali FS and will
        write to this file all test log output (colored).
        :param: testname: test name - recieved from pytest fixtures (command line parameters)
        :param: setup: test setup - recieved from pytest fixtures (command line parameters)
        :param: silent: log test in silent mode (info only) or not silent mode (everything is logged)
        :param: root_password: password for root user
        """
    ....

...
```

and in the conftest.py file I wrote the function that will be invoked when this logger will be requested (creating a logger fixture)

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="module",autouse=True)
def logger(request):
    setup = request.config.getoption('--setupname')
    logger = Logger(testname=request.node.name, setup=setup)
    return logger
```

Now, my question is how do I make this concrete logger global using pytest?
Meaning I don't want to pass it as argument to the test function like this:

```
def test_logger(other_fixture,logger):
```

but still be able to use it inside the `test_logger` test function (like global variable)

Comment: Make it a global variable on module level, e.g. `pytest.logger = logger` in conftest.

Comment: who said that pytest has field named logger? 
I don't understand what you are suggesting

Comment: You will assign that field yourself via the line in the above comment. A variable can't be magically made available in any function scope, it must be declared somewhere. The suggestion is to make `logger` a global variable by assigning it at module level; you can select any module of course, but `pytest` makes most sense IMO.

Comment: and how can I call the logger from other module after the assignment?

Comment: Via `import pytest; logger = pytest.logger`, not?

Comment: this is the output I get from pytest debbuger:   
`E   AttributeError: module 'pytest' has no attribute 'logger' `  
I have wrote `pytest.logger = logger` in conftest 
`

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I think I've got it! Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: @ms_stud how did you solve this?

Answer (score 9):

You could do

```py
@pytest.mark.usefixtures("logger")
def test_logger(other_fixture):
```